# Couldn't get connection factory client after re installing OS

Tags: android

First time when I got api key generating MD5 finger print My app was running fine.
But after formatting my windows 7 OS and re installing now I am getting "MapActivity : Couldn't get connection factory client" error.I am getting new MD5 finger print with keytool
than before I got But with this new finger print,I can not generate api key It says "The fingerprint you entered is not valid". On the other hand submitting old MD5 finger print I am getting the the same old api key which does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time I have made MD5 finger print with jk6
but after re installing my Operating System I made MD5 finger print with jdk7.
whatever again re installing OS I have made MD5 finger print with jdk6 now this time api key is working fine but still getting "Couldn't get connection factory client" in Log cat.

May be for this reason it was not working.